# Variable Not Changing in If Statement with Sarxos Motion Detection

Tags: java

I'm trying to have my program print a few "funny" images whenever it detects motion. Everything works by itself but when I put the if(detection == true) statement into the program, the variable doesn't update. How could I get it to update inside of the motionDetected function?

I've tried using boolean and int for the variable but I think it could be with the way I've structured it.

```
package printstuff;



import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import java.util.function.Function;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies;

import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamMotionDetector;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamMotionEvent;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamMotionListener;
/**
 * Detect motion.
 * 
 * @author Bartosz Firyn (SarXos)
 */
public class DetectMotion implements WebcamMotionListener {

    public static boolean detection = false;

    public DetectMotion() {

        //creates a webcam motion detector

        WebcamMotionDetector detector = new WebcamMotionDetector(Webcam.getDefault());
        detector.setInterval(100); // one check per 100 ms
        detector.addMotionListener(this);
        detector.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void motionDetected(WebcamMotionEvent wme) {
        //detects motion and should change the detection variable
        System.out.println("Detected motion");
        detection = true;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
        new DetectMotion();
        System.in.read(); // keep program open

        final String[] catImages = new String[4];
        //all the images
        catImages[0] = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3v79CLLhoyE/maxresdefault.jpg";
        catImages[1] = "https://i.imgur.com/RFS6RUv.jpg";
        catImages[2] = "https://kiwifarms.net/attachments/dozgry5w4ae3cut-jpg.618924/";
        catImages[3] = "https://www.foodiecrush.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Instant-Pot-Macaroni-and-Cheese-foodiecrush.com-019.jpg";        
        //statement does not work..
        if(detection == true)
        {
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {

        //saves the picture inside of the array to image.jpg
        String imageUrl = catImages[i];
        String destinationFile = "image.jpg";

        saveImage(imageUrl, destinationFile);

        //sends print job to printer

         PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            pras.add(new Copies(1));
            PrintService pss[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, pras);
            if (pss.length == 0)
              throw new RuntimeException("No printer services available.");
            PrintService ps = pss[0];
            System.out.println("Printing to " + ps);
            DocPrintJob job = ps.createPrintJob();
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("image.jpg");
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fin, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, null);
            job.print(doc, pras);
            fin.close();

            java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(15);

        }
    }
    }   
public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {
    //converts url into image
    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

    byte[] b = new byte[2048];
    int length;

    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
        os.write(b, 0, length);
    }

    is.close();
    os.close();
}

}
```

Comment: from the looks of it, I would guess that `detection` is set by another thread. Have you tried declaring it as `volatile`?

Comment: Your `main` method gets stuck at `System.in.read()`.  Once you type something, it will continue on.

Comment: Maybe you should put `if(detection == true) {...}` into a `while(true)` loop

Comment: @Turing85 I added 'volatile' to the declare statement and it prints as true inside of the 'motionDetected' function, but it is still causing the if statement to work.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Typing something did break it. Is there anyway to do that automatically?

Comment: @Blobonat putting `while(true)` doesn't seem to make a difference in the program

Comment: Are you asking how to NOT have that line in your program?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem No, it's just that it is required to detect the motion. I'm trying to figure out how to close it so that it can move on to my while statement. Can I break it in the middle? Or is there another function that I can use to replicate it?

Comment: No, that line is _not_ required to detect the motion.  It has nothing to do with detecting motion.  In terms of what you're trying to achieve though, maybe you should move all the code associated with selecting an image and printing it to your `motionDetected` method instead of `main`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I am fairly new to programming so I do apologize for asking possibly obvious questions, but when I removed the `System.in.read()` the motion capture device deallocated and shutdown, causing my program not to run. Also moving everything to `motionDetected` caused my `saveImage` function to not work and I cannot throw IOException in there.